# How to call the methods of a delegator from the wrapped object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, delegation

Let's say I have this class and delegator

```
class MyObject
  def foo
    "foo #{bar}"
  end 

  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

class MyDelegator < SimpleDelegator
  def bar
    "decorated bar"
  end
end

MyDelegator.new(MyObject.new).foo # => "foo bar"
```

This obviously happens because of the method resolution chain. `#foo` is not found on the `MyDelegator` class, therefore it is delegated to the `MyObject` class. When `MyObject#foo` is called, the method in turn calls `MyObject#bar`.

I can have `MyDelegator#foo` return `"foo decorated bar"` this way:

```
class MyObject
  def foo
    "foo #{bar}"
  end 

  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

class MyDelegator < SimpleDelegator
  module MyMethods
    def bar
      "decorated bar"
    end
  end

  def initialize(object)
    super
    object.singleton_class.include(object)
  end
end

MyDelegator.new(MyObject.new).foo # => "foo decorated bar"
```

I could also have defined methods on the eigenclass of the `MyObject` instance using `define_method` or `instance_eval` for example. My question is the following:

Is there a way I can achieve the same thing without changing the eigenclass of the wrapped object and without cloning it while keeping the wrapped object untouched for other consumers of the object downstream?